# C array value gets negated sometimes

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, casting

I am trying to put an integer value into a character array so I can have byte addressable memory. When I pass the integer I want to place and the character pointer to the array into my function they have the correct values. After the assignment the integer pointer keeps the correct value but the character pointer has the negative value. This only happens two times out of ten and on the same two numbers every time..
Here is a snippet of the function

```
//Places an int into an array at memLocation
void PutIntAt(int i, char *arr)
{
    printf("value: %i at: %i\n", i, arr - &mainMemory[0]);
    int *pos = (int*)arr;
    *pos = i;
    printf("*pos is: %x *arr is: %x\n", *pos, *arr);
}
```

The output I get from this i

```
value: 150 at: 28
*pos is: 96 *arr is: ffffff96
value: 50 at: 32
*pos is: 32 *arr is: 32
value: 20 at: 36
*pos is: 14 *arr is: 14
value: 10 at: 40
*pos is: a *arr is: a
value: 5 at: 44
*pos is: 5 *arr is: 5
value: 500 at: 48
*pos is: 1f4 *arr is: fffffff4
location 48 = -12
```

I am compiling with gcc and using the `-o` option and `-std=gnu99` option.
The `mainMemory` array is a global variable. Not sure why this is happening.

Comment: Q:  Not sure why this is happening... A: Maybe because both *arr and mainMemory might be defined as char, and any result of signed char  arithmetic  >= 128 will result in a negative number?

Comment: It's hard to see where the problem might be without seeing rest of your code. Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @ameyCU 
When I declare main memory I do it statically with this line:
char mainMemory[MEM_SIZE];
where MEM_SIZE is 5000
@ paulsm4
I thought the same thing initially but the value 300 get properly converted one line before 150 doesn't..

Comment: @jgleesti how is `arr` declared ?

Comment: It's because you are passing a char to printf, which is *arr, but you are telling the format specifier to interpret it as a 32 bit hex value. By contrast, *pos is an int

Comment: @ameyCU
PutIntAt(tokint, &mainMemory[directiveMemLocation]);
where directiveMemLocation is where I want to insert into mainMemory

Comment: @samgak I thought that might be the case as well but later in my program I cast that memory location into an integer again and it gives me the negative value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong format specifier for `printf`. This causes undefined behaviour.

You use `%x`, which requires `unsigned int`,  but supplied `*arr` which is a `char`. On your system `char` has a range that includes negative values.

To fix this you could either use the `%hhd` or `%d` specifiers (the latter works due to default argument promotion).  If you want to convert the `char` to unsigned then you have to write code to perform a conversion, e.g.:

```
printf("%x\n", (unsigned char)*arr);
```

Note: The printf specification is not very clearly written, but it's generally interpreted that `%u` and `%x` may be used with any smaller argument which gets promoted to a non-negative integer.  So you can use `%x` rather than `%hhx` in my example.

Comment: Using %hhd both pointers print a negative value. I think this is getting me in the right direction. I'm guessing that they print negative values because The integer takes up two bytes of space and I'm only printing one byte?

Comment: They print negative values because you are passing a negative value as argument.  Your code is basically `printf("%d", -2);` and you asking why it prints `-2`. Consider using `unsigned char *arr` instead.

Comment: Oh wow.. this whole time I thought `%i` was for unsigned integers. I was sure that I was passing a positive value, turns out it wasn't. Thanks @M.M.. Feeling a little sheepish now

Comment: @jgleesti `%i` is a synonym for `%d`, in printf. (Has different meaning in scanf).